# C++ programing first on Windows then on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, windows, ubuntu, codeblocks

I have been writing few codes in CodeBlocks in C++, on windows, now I want to try a new op system(Ubuntu). I have already installed Ubuntu and CodeBlocks on another PC, and I tested the simple "hello world" program, which runs just fine. But when I copy my .cbp and other files from my windows PC to my Ubuntu PC, and try to run the same program which worked just fine on the windows PC, doesn't work on the Ubuntu PC. It gives me a lot of build error messages, I have tried to re-install g++, gpp, gcc, mingwin and CodeBlocks, but the problem is still unsolved.
I don't know if I can give you exact error messages, because I have tried with several projects and it looks like in every project it gives me other errors.

Here are some example errors:
(When I try to double click on it, it doesn't show where it found the problem, ie.: in line 32, it says that it can be found in line 511, however the project is only around 100 lines)
undefined reference to '_imp_isprint'
undefined reference to '_imp_acrt_iob_func'

I can make and run the files from the terminal, with the 'make' and './***' command, but I want to build it through CodeBlocks.

If you need any more information please contact me.

Comment: Have you tried... `#include <iostream>` and `int main() { std::cout << "Hello world.\n"; }`?

Comment: To compile linux native binaries you will not need mingw.

Comment: I have tried to make a whole new project on the Ubuntu pc, and it worked fine. But when I try to copy any file, it runs into errors.

Comment: Maybe your .cbp has OS specific information. This is one reason why there are programs like CMake that generate project files for you

Comment: That's what I thoght first, but my teacher is praising Linux, and asked us to us it, therefor I don't think that he would give us a skeleton program which can only be built in Windows.

Comment: You probably need to make your own project file on linux. Also I believe a .cpb file is plan text ( I have not used code::blocks in more than 10 years). So if you see `c:` at all in the file you already know the answer that it contains windows specific paths that won't work on linux.